# Import classes from submodules into (aliased) namespace

Tags: python, alias, package, python-import, python-module

I have the following package structure:

```
package_name/
    __init__.py
    some_module.py
    another_module.py
    # other classes
```

I'm using this package from another Python file, in which I would like to do the following:

- declare an alias for `package_name`

  ```
  import package_name as pn
  ```
- and refer to classes inside `some_module.py`, `another_module.py`, etc. as follows:

  ```
  instance = pn.SomeClass(pn.AnotherClass(x, y))
  ```

  i.e. omitting the module name and instead using only the package name alias.

Something like this:

```
import package_name as pn
from package_name import some_module to pn
```

Is this, or anything equivalent, possible?

---

I can do this:

```
from package_name.some_module import SomeClass
from package_name.another_module import AnotherClass
instance = SomeClass(AnotherClass(x, y))
```

and this:

```
import package_name.some_module
import package_name.another_module
instance = pn.some_module.SomeClass(pn.some_module.AnotherClass(x, y))
```

but this doesn't work

```
import package_name.some_module as pn
import package_name.another_module as pn
instance = pn.SomeClass(pn.AnotherClass(x, y))
```

because the second `as pn` overrides the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to import a single module from the package is:

```
from package_name import some_module as pn
```

To have access from `package_name` to the classes defined inside the other modules, the right thing to do is to import these classes, explictly or using some tool, to the `__init__.py` file inside package_name:

`package_name/__init__.py`:

```
from .some_module import a_class
from .another_module import another_class
```

And that will allow you to simply do:

```
import package_name as pn
pn.a_class
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion doesn't work for more than one `import` but importing the classes in `__init__.py` does the trick.